# How to read and assign a value to a python variable from (.db) file

Tags: python, database

I am trying to extract virtualIP and onvifPort from a (.db) file.

I have a database.db file, which looks like this:

```
    {
    "devices": {
        "193619374120978": {
            "cameras": {
                "14:a7:8b:08:e0:7c": {
                    "slots": {
                        "3": {
                            "onvifPort": "17005",
                            "rtspPort": "18005",
                            "virtualIP": "10.27.15.75",
                            "pubIP": "",
                            "pubOnvifPort": "0",
                            "pubRtspPort": "0"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "ac:cc:8e:a8:84:e1": {
                    "slots": {
                        "2": {
                            "onvifPort": "17003",
                            "rtspPort": "18003",
                            "virtualIP": "10.27.15.75",
                            "pubIP": "",
                            "pubOnvifPort": "0",
                            "pubRtspPort": "0"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "14:a7:8b:22:86:f6": {
                    "slots": {
                        "1": {
                            "onvifPort": "17004",
                            "rtspPort": "18004",
                            "virtualIP": "10.27.15.75",
                            "pubIP": "",
                            "pubOnvifPort": "0",
                            "pubRtspPort": "0"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have to read this file using python and assign this values to python variables.

I am new to python and I just tried something like this, but I am not getting the desired output. I would like to know how to open and read a (.db) file and assign the values

```
    

with open("bmdatabase.db","r") as infile:
    inputs = json.load(infile)
#con = sqlite3.connect('bmdatabase.db')
#c = con.cursor()
for item in range(len(inputs["devices[].cameras[].slots[]"])):
    IP = inputs["devices[].cameras[].slots[]"][item]["virtualIP"]
    PORT = inputs["devices[].cameras[].slots[]"][item]["onvifPort"]
```

expected output:
username and password should be constant for all the 3 devices

```
 
    IP = virtualIP of slot[1]from database.db file
    PORT = onvifPort of slot[1] from database.db file
    USERNAME = "admin" 
    PASSWORD = "Abcd"

    IP = virtualIP of slot[2]from database.db file
    PORT = onvifPort of slot[2] from database.db file
    USERNAME = "admin" 
    PASSWORD = "Abcd"

    IP = virtualIP of slot[3]from database.db file
    PORT = onvifPort of slot[3] from database.db file
    USERNAME = "admin" 
    PASSWORD = "Abcd"
```

can anyone help me with this??

Comment: Can you edit your question and put there expected output?

Comment: @AndrejKesely edited, you can check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this example to parse your data:

```
db = {
    "devices": {
        "193619374120978": {
            "cameras": {
                "14:a7:8b:08:e0:7c": {
                    "slots": {
                        "3": {
                            "onvifPort": "17005",
                            "rtspPort": "18005",
                            "virtualIP": "10.27.15.75",
                            "pubIP": "",
                            "pubOnvifPort": "0",
                            "pubRtspPort": "0"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "ac:cc:8e:a8:84:e1": {
                    "slots": {
                        "2": {
                            "onvifPort": "17003",
                            "rtspPort": "18003",
                            "virtualIP": "10.27.15.75",
                            "pubIP": "",
                            "pubOnvifPort": "0",
                            "pubRtspPort": "0"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "14:a7:8b:22:86:f6": {
                    "slots": {
                        "1": {
                            "onvifPort": "17004",
                            "rtspPort": "18004",
                            "virtualIP": "10.27.15.75",
                            "pubIP": "",
                            "pubOnvifPort": "0",
                            "pubRtspPort": "0"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


parsed = []
for device_id in db['devices']:
    for camera_mac in db['devices'][device_id]['cameras']:
        for slot in db['devices'][device_id]['cameras'][camera_mac]['slots']:
            parsed.append({
                'IP': db['devices'][device_id]['cameras'][camera_mac]['slots'][slot]['virtualIP'],
                'PORT': db['devices'][device_id]['cameras'][camera_mac]['slots'][slot]['onvifPort'],
                'USERNAME': 'admin',
                'PASSWORD': 'Abcd'
            })


from pprint import pprint
pprint(parsed)
```

Prints:

```
[{'IP': '10.27.15.75',
  'PASSWORD': 'Abcd',
  'PORT': '17005',
  'USERNAME': 'admin'},
 {'IP': '10.27.15.75',
  'PASSWORD': 'Abcd',
  'PORT': '17003',
  'USERNAME': 'admin'},
 {'IP': '10.27.15.75',
  'PASSWORD': 'Abcd',
  'PORT': '17004',
  'USERNAME': 'admin'}]
```

---

EDIT: To load the data from file

```
import json
db = json.load(open('<your file-name>', 'r'))
print(db)
```

Comment: can you also, please tell me how to open the (db) file and get the values from it

Comment: @saivamsi The file seems like it's a Json. You can use `json` module to load it. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
for device in inputs["devices"]:
    for camera in device["cameras"]:
        for slot in camera["slots"]:
            IP = slot["virtualIP"]
            PORT = slot["onvifPort"]
```